Relation between the Stirling numbers of first and second kind
Definitions:
Let $c(n,k)$ denote the number of permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles.The Stirling numbers of the first kind, $s(n,k)$, is defined as the number of permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles times the sign $(-1)^{n-k}$, i.e. $s(n,k)=(-1)^{n-k}c(n,k)$.
The Stirling numbers of the second kind, $S(n,k)$, is the number of partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ parts.

Thoughts:
We know that a permuation $p \in S_n$, can be decomposed into cycles $p_1,...,p_l$. Let's consider those permutations that can be decomposed into $k$ cycles. For those cycles $p_1,...,p_k$ their Images $Im(p_1),...,Im(p_k)$ are pairwise disjoint (a consequence of being cycles). But this means that $Im(p_1),...,Im(p_k)$ partition the set [n] into $k$ parts.
Question:
Does this now mean that $c(n,k)=S(n,k)$ and the only difference between the Stirling numbers of the first and the second kind is a (possibly) different sign?
